# Saving a PFFile into cloud - where did it go?

Tags: parse-platform

According the the Files section of the Parse documentation, to save a `PFFile`, we should follow these steps:

1. Create the `PFFile`
2. Save the `PFFile` to the cloud
3. After saving completes, associate the `PFFile` with a `PFObject`

I have troubles visualizing step #2. Here's the example code they provided, which I tried to run myself:

```
//1. Creating the PFFile
let str = "Working with Parse is great!"
let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let file = PFFile(name: "resume.txt", data: data)

//2. Saving the PFFile
file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { succeeded, error in
    if error != nil {
        println(error)
    }
    if succeeded {
        println("succeeded saving PFFile to cloud")
    }
}
```

When I ran the code, the file succeeded in saving. But upon checking in my Parse app database, I see nothing that indicates the object is saved.

What is the point of step #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #2 doesn't result in anything visible in the Parse database browser. It uploads the file, but nothing references it so it's not visible. You need to associate it with an object, and then it'll be visible via the field you save it in within that object.

Also, if you look in the Settings -> General area in Parse.com for your app, near the bottom of the main pane, you'll see a link for "Clean Up Files". I believe this looks at all the files that have been uploaded, but are not associated with any objects in your database, and removes them.